# Необходимо реализовать удаление объекта "студент" из массива

Tags: javascript

Студенты выводятся в виде таблицы, необходимо реализовать возможность их удаления с кнопки, как из массива, где эти студенты и находятся, так и визуально удалить строку из таблицы. Говорю честно-очень туплю, но и, прежде чем писать сюда, искал информацию в интернете. Там предлагались такие варианты, как

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('document').ready(function() {
    $("td").click(function (){
        var selectId= document.getElementsByName('table_id').value

        alert('already clicked '+selectId);});
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

и

```
function SomeDeleteRowFunction() {
  // event.target will be the input element.
  var td = event.target.parentNode; 
  var tr = td.parentNode; // the row to be removed
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);}
```

Но ничего из этого не сработало. Вот [ccылка](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nQQ_f0n4guSzPqj4REyj59V05Ss9zm_z?usp=share_link) на гугл драйв с проектом.

Comment: Чтобы получить ответ перенесите код в вопрос в снипет (уберите из кода все что не относится к проблеме удаления и сделайте максимально простую разметку) так Вы создадите минимально воспроизводимый пример, далее продемострируйте какие правки вы вносили и куда. Так есть вероятность что Ваш вопрос не заминусуют и Вы получите ответ.

Comment: Где студенты в виде таблицы? Как вообще выглядят объекты студентов? То, что Вы нашли в интернете, Вы написали, а сами как пытались решить проблему?

Answer (score 3):

Принцип удаления должен быть примерно такой:

```js
const btns = [...document.getElementsByClassName('btn')];

btns.map(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
table, td{
border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Имя</th>
  <th>Фамилия</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Василий</td>
    <td>Пупкин</td>
    <td><button class="btn">Удалить</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Семен</td>
    <td>Непомнящий</td>
    <td><button class="btn">Удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Мария</td>
    <td>Облигация</td>
    <td><button class="btn">Удалить</button></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Вариант с делигированием:

```js
const students = document.getElementById('students');

students.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('btn')) {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table id="students">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Имя</th>
      <th>Фамилия</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Василий</td>
      <td>Пупкин</td>
      <td><button class="btn">Удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Семен</td>
      <td>Непомнящий</td>
      <td><button class="btn">Удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Мария</td>
      <td>Облигация</td>
      <td><button class="btn">Удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ужасно, лучше воспользоваться делегированием. И все же воспользоваться методом `closest`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson  Для того, чтобы человек понял как это работает делегирование не подойдет. Оно не такое очевидное.

Comment: Тоже проголосую за closest()

Comment: @PavelNazarian По какой причине?

Comment: @Andrei как минимум, это короче, а также при обрастании дополнительными html тегами не нужно будет дописывать новые паренты

Comment: @PavelNazarian А как Вы думаете, что лучше? Указать точное расположение в DOM необходимого html элемента или искать его рекурсивно.

Comment: @Andrei смотря для чего или кого лучше. Вы спросили я ответил. Вас не устраивают аргументы, я не настаиваю. Это была не нотация.

Comment: @PavelNazarian Совершенно с Вами согласен. Потому Вы должны понять абсурдность комментариев, давайте используем ту или иную функцию без причины. Решая не понятные задачи нахождения сферического коня в вакууме.